# How to read a Windows 10 BSOD mini dump analysis

Tags: windows, windows-10, minidump

I'm hoping someone here can help.

I have a new Windows 10 machine (all parts by EVGA).

I get random BSOD, so I've grabbed a mini dump, installed the SDK and looked into it. I just don't understand what it is reporting.

Can someone point me in the direction of a guide, or decode this mini dump.
Note : Each dump looks very similar. e.g. almost the same report from 'irp'

Here is the dump....

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 X86
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\033016-4718-01.dmp]
>   Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available
>
> Symbol search path is: srv*
>   Executable search path is: 
>   Windows 10 Kernel Version 10586 MP (8 procs) Free x64
>   Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
>   Built by: 10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728
>   Machine Name:
>   Kernel base = 0xfffff801`8d674000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`8d952cd0
>   Debug session time: Wed Mar 30 18:15:33.639 2016 (UTC + 1:00)
>   System Uptime: 0 days 2:47:26.264
>   Loading Kernel Symbols
>   .
>
> Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
>   Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.
>
> ..............................................................
>   ................................................................
>   ................................
>   Loading User Symbols
>   Loading unloaded module list
>   .............
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
>
> BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffe000935ea880, fffff8018f25a890, ffffe00092718bd0}
>
> Probably caused by : ACPI.sys
>
> ### Followup:     MachineOwner
>
> 0: kd> !analyze -v
>
> ---

- *
- Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
- *

  ---

> DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
>   A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
>   Arguments:
>   Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
>   Arg2: ffffe000935ea880, Physical Device Object of the stack
>   Arg3: fffff8018f25a890, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
>   Arg4: ffffe00092718bd0, The blocked IRP
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> DUMP_CLASS: 1
>
> DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400
>
> BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728
>
> SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  EVGA INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD
>
> SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Default string
>
> SYSTEM_SKU:  Default string
>
> SYSTEM_VERSION:  Default string
>
> BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.
>
> BIOS_VERSION:  1.07
>
> BIOS_DATE:  01/04/2016
>
> BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  EVGA INTERNATIONAL CO.,LTD
>
> BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  111-SS-E172
>
> BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0
>
> DUMP_TYPE:  2
>
> DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x8
>     Kernel Generated Triage Dump
>
> BUGCHECK_P1: 3
>
> BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe000935ea880
>
> BUGCHECK_P3: fffff8018f25a890
>
> BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe00092718bd0
>
> DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  ACPI.sys
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  56cbf9c9
>
> MODULE_NAME: ACPI
>
> FAULTING_MODULE: fffff800d5de0000 ACPI
>
> CPU_COUNT: 8
>
> CPU_MHZ: d50
>
> CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel
>
> CPU_FAMILY: 6
>
> CPU_MODEL: 5e
>
> CPU_STEPPING: 3
>
> CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 33'00000000 (cache) 33'00000000 (init)
>
> CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  System
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  2
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  Q-PC
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  03-30-2016 20:04:47.0460
>
> ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 x86fre
>
> STACK_TEXT:
>   fffff801`8f25a858 fffff801`8d854e42 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffe000`935ea880 fffff801`8f25a890 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
>   fffff801`8f25a860 fffff801`8d854d62 : ffffe000`96133010 fffff801`8f252070 00000000`00000000 fffff801`8d73e0a6 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xde
>   fffff801`8f25a8c0 fffff801`8d6e22c6 : ffffe000`96133048 fffff801`8f25aa10 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x32
>   fffff801`8f25a910 fffff801`8d7b951a : 00000000`00000000 fffff801`8d991180 fffff801`8da07740 ffffe000`96723800 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x5f6
>   fffff801`8f25ab60 00000000`00000000 : fffff801`8f25b000 fffff801`8f254000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  kb
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  81a7ba75a791115b4f55c8910c64a260d525502e
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  936d5c51c0ad2157bf4c85af575dd55cea2c0947
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f08ac56120cad14894587db086f77ce277bfae84
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10586.122
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_i8042prt_IMAGE_ACPI.sys
>
> BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_i8042prt_IMAGE_ACPI.sys
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_i8042prt_IMAGE_ACPI.sys
>
> TARGET_TIME:  2016-03-30T17:15:33.000Z
>
> OSBUILD:  10586
>
> OSSERVICEPACK:  0
>
> SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
>
> OS_REVISION: 0
>
> SUITE_MASK:  272
>
> PRODUCT_TYPE:  1
>
> OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
>
> OSNAME:  Windows 10
>
> OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS
>
> OS_LOCALE:
>
> USER_LCID:  0
>
> OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-02-24 05:48:00
>
> BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160223-1728
>
> BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_sec
>
> BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.162.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160223-1728
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 3d7
>
> ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
>
> FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_i8042prt_image_acpi.sys
>
> FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {22a3ff34-49ca-8d37-715b-ae023b6cc9fb}
>
> ### Followup:     MachineOwner
>
> 0: kd> !irp ffffe00092718bd0
>   Irp is active with 8 stacks 6 is current (= 0xffffe00092718e08)
>    No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  Pending has been returned
>        cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
>    [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
>               0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000

```
        Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

[N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000

```
        Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

[N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000

> ```
>         Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
> ```
>
> [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
>               0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000

```
        Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffffe000935ea880 00000000 fffff800d6a81ec0-00000000
           \Driver\ACPI i8042prt!I8xPowerUpToD0Complete
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002

> [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
>               0 e1 ffffe00093f936f0 00000000 fffff800d6ab1060-00000000 Success Error Cancel pending
>              \Driver\i8042prt kbdclass!KeyboardClassPowerComplete
>               Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
>    [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
>               0 e1 ffffe00093dc95f0 00000000 fffff8018d7840b8-ffffe00096133010 Success Error Cancel pending
>              \Driver\kbdclass nt!PopRequestCompletion
>               Args: 00051100 00000001 00000001 00000002
>    [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
>               0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe00096133010
>
> ```
>         Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
> ```

---

I'm also adding a BlueScreen screen shot, incase that helps.

[image: bluescreen]

---

Now adding output from some extra commands after Martins comments...

```
0: kd> !devstack ffffe000935ea880
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe00093dc95f0  \Driver\kbdclass   ffffe00093dc9740  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe00093dc95c0

  ffffe00093f936f0  \Driver\i8042prt   ffffe00093f93840  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe00093f936c0

> ffffe000935ea880  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000923fa8d0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe000935d6af0 :
  DeviceInst is "ACPI\PNP0303\0"
  ServiceName is "i8042prt"




!process 0 7
**** NT ACTIVE PROCESS DUMP ****
GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff8018d9f3200
Error in reading nt!_EPROCESS at 0000000000000000




0: kd> !poaction
PopAction: fffff8018d94efe0
  State..........: 0 - Idle
  Updates........: 0 
  Action.........: None
  Lightest State.: Unspecified
  Flags..........: 10000003 QueryApps|UIAllowed
  Irp minor......: ??
  System State...: Unspecified
  Hiber Context..: 0000000000000000

Allocated power irps (PopIrpList - fffff8018d94f4f0)
  IRP: ffffe00092718bd0 (set/D0,), PDO: ffffe000935ea880, CURRENT: ffffe00093f936f0
  IRP: ffffe000971aa990

Irp worker threads (PopIrpThreadList - fffff8018d94e100)
  THREAD: ffffe00091515040 (static)
  THREAD: ffffe00091501800 (static)

Error resolving nt!_POP_CURRENT_BROADCAST...
```

---

Summary: Error was caused by my 10 year old Razor mouse with Windows 10.
The driver when entering power save state was freaking out and causing the blue screen.

I purchased a new mouse, removed the driver & 2 months in no more BSOD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) by Nirsoft. It will get you a list of last BSOD and will show a nice view of the components. "Normally" the first mentioned component could be the reason.

Not sure, if you are looking for a solution on a specific problem or the minidump usage in general.
Some driver got problems with power state change. Make sure, you have the current Drivers installed.

Comment: This just shows "DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE ntoskrnl.exe"  Then Parameter 1 is 000000..000003, I'm not sure what else it is telling me, I can add a screen shot of it.

Comment: Try followng this article: http://www.codemachine.com/article_debugging0x9F.html  They seem to show debugging exactly  your bugcheck.

Comment: Powerful tool to have in the arsenal. Thank you! Managed to find the culprit, in my case: `em008k_64.dll`.